# Flutter: How to avoid vivo safe keyboard cover a password input field?

Tags: android, flutter, input, keyboard

I am developing a flutter App.I noticed that the vivo safe keyboard was obscuring the input field when I used vivo X60 debugging the app.Even
though official sample form app.How can I deal with this problem?

I tried to search the internet, but no useful results.Other mobile phone models (includs:huawei p40,vivo Y3,mi 11) is normal.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this property in the **Scaffold**:

```
resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true
```

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work. That's what I said, other mobile phone models is normal. I think it's a problem with specific phone.

Comment: Yes it can be because of that